# SwiftUI - how to animate a pre-existing view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a ViewContainer that is defined like this:

```
struct ViewContainer<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    let backgroundColor: Color
    let borderColor: Color

    init(backgroundColor: Color = .gray, borderColor: Color = .clear, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.borderColor = borderColor
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content
        }
        .padding()
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(borderColor, lineWidth: 1)
        )
    }

    func flash() {
        ???
    }
}
```

And I add it to view hierarchies like this:

```
ViewContainer(backgroundColor: Color.white.opacity(0.3), borderColor: .white) {
    // some content
}
```

But I need to be able to later (on some button tap for example) have the background of the ViewContainer flash to some other color (say .red for example), and then fade back to its original color. How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach:
You pass in two additional parameters to your ViewContainer – `flash` and `flashColor`. `flash` sends the signal for changing the background color. But as its animation back to normal is controlled by the ViewContainer, it has to be passed in as `@Binding`, so it can be reset inside ViewContainer.

Note that you'll still need a `@State var` in the parent view to keep track of the button press state.

```
struct ViewContainer<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    let backgroundColor: Color
    let borderColor: Color
    
    @Binding var flash: Bool // hand over flash var as binding, so it can be reset inside this view
    let flashColor: Color

    init(backgroundColor: Color = .gray,
         borderColor: Color = .clear,
         flash: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false),
         flashColor: Color = .clear,
         @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.borderColor = borderColor
        self._flash = flash // note the underscore to access the binding underlying value
        self.flashColor = flashColor
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content
        }
        .padding()
        .background(flash ? flashColor : backgroundColor) // show flash color if flash == true
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(borderColor, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        
        // on change of flash animate back
        .onChange(of: flash) { _ in
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 2)) {
                flash = false
            }
        }
    }

}



struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var buttonPressed = false // you still need a state var here to keep track of the button press
    
    var body: some View {
        ViewContainer(backgroundColor: Color.green.opacity(0.3), borderColor: .blue, flash: $buttonPressed, flashColor: .red) {
            // some content
            Text("Hello, World!")
            
            Button("Flash") {
                buttonPressed = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```